# How to read a file, reverse the order, and write reverse order

Tags: java, file-io, indexoutofboundsexception

Like a similar project I made, this project is reading characters from a txt file, reversing the order of the string and rewriting it to another txt file. But it keeps outputting my exception of "Something went wrong". Can anyone help me fix what is going wrong?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
       {
          try{
          String source = args[0];
          String target = args[1];

          File sourceFile=new File(source);

          Scanner content=new Scanner(sourceFile);
          PrintWriter pwriter =new PrintWriter(target);

          while(content.hasNextLine())
          {
             String s=content.nextLine();
             StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(s);
             buffer=buffer.reverse();
             String rs=buffer.toString();
             pwriter.println(rs);
          }
          content.close();    
          pwriter.close();
          System.out.println("File is copied successful!");
          }

          catch(Exception e){
              System.out.println("Something went wrong");
          }
       }
}
```

So here is the information from the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at ReverseFile.main(ReverseFile.java:36)
```

Comment: A stack-trace would help..

Comment: something went wrong? can you paste the full stack trace

Comment: 1) Change `catch(Exception e){
              System.out.println("Something went wrong");` to `catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();
              System.out.println("Something went wrong");` and copy/paste the output as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16138380/edit). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: You should almost *never* do `catch(Exception e)`. This loses critical information which you need to figure out problems when something goes wrong, such as the line number that caused the problem in the first place.

Comment: Could the down-voters be a little patient for edits or explain why they are down-voting?  I am confused.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks, I mean really...

Comment: @ElizabethTurner- Are you passing the two filenames while running the program?

Comment: @vidit no, just plain java ReverseFile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am not so sure about your environment, and how long the text might be. and i am also not so sure why you need a scanner?

anyway, here's my take on the problem, hope this helps you :)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.io.Reader;


public class Reverse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        RandomAccessFile raf = null;

        // by default, let's use utf-8
        String characterEncoding = "utf-8";

        // but if you pass an optional 3rd parameter, we use that
        if(args.length==3) {
            characterEncoding = args[2];
        }

        try{

            // input file
            File in = new File(args[0]);
            fis = new FileInputStream(in);

            // a reader, because it respects character encoding etc
            Reader r = new InputStreamReader(fis,characterEncoding);

            // an outputfile 
            File out = new File(args[1]);

            // and a random access file of the same size as the input, so we can write in reverse order 
            raf = new RandomAccessFile(out, "rw");
            raf.setLength(in.length());

            // a buffer for the chars we want to read 
            char[] buff = new char[1];

            // keep track of the current position (we're going backwards, so we start at the end)
            long position = in.length(); 

            // Reader.read will return -1 when it reached the end.
            while((r.read(buff))>-1) {

                // turn the character into bytes according to the character encoding
                Character c = buff[0];
                String s = c+"";
                byte[] bBuff = s.getBytes(characterEncoding);

                // go to the proper position in the random access file
                position = position-bBuff.length;
                raf.seek(position);

                // write one or more bytes for the character
                raf.write(bBuff);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // clean up
            try {
                fis.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
            }
            try {
                raf.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
            }
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Actually I just tried your code and i get a similar error to the one I have. Could it just be me?
`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at ReverseFile.main(ReverseFile.java:50)`

Comment: i'll post a modified version that prints more helpful stuff ... wait a few minutes

Comment: actually I typed in my cmdline wrong, your code does work, but the output is all on 1 line. Close enough for government work I say.

Comment: hi. well, you could change it to do line by line. this code treat linbreaks just like normal characters.

Comment: if you're on windows, this might be weird, because on windows, a linebreak is actually TWO characters (\r\n), and if you reverse it, it will come out a \n\r ... i am not so sure what happens in this case.

Comment: yeah can't say im that worried about it. Thanks for the help! *kiss*

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the filenames(source and target) on command-line, while running the program.

```
java ReverseFile source.txt target.txt
```

In your program, you try to read the name of files from command-line as

```
String source = args[0];
String target = args[1];
```

So if you do not specify those names there, `java` tries to access the array `args` at index 0 and 1 which are empty and you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: This is the exception I get when run like suggested:

`Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:    \file.txt (The system
cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at ReverseFile.main(ReverseFile.java:49)`

Comment: Are those files in the same directory as the class file?

Comment: yes they are both in the same directory as the class file. The files names are in.txt and out.txt if that makes any difference

Comment: @ElizabethTurner - then you need to use those names on the command-line.

Comment: Are you still getting the same exception? Because from the exception you posted above in comment, seems like java is trying to read "file.txt"

Comment: @ElizabethTurner: If you actually run exactly the code you posted, and call it like `java ReverseFile in.txt out.txt` it will never say `java.io.FileNotFoundException: \file.txt`. Please make absolutely sure the code you posted is the code you run. Also edit your question, include how you are calling it and post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking as well, and I don't know why that is. I've looked my code up and down and see no mention of this "file.txt" that the error is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

here is ur error free solution to ur problem,u were using "Scanner" without importing "util"
package.here we go:-----------

```
   import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

        public class ReverseFile
         {
         public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
          {
      try{
      File sourceFile=new File(args[0]);
      Scanner content=new Scanner(sourceFile);
      PrintWriter pwriter =new PrintWriter(args[1]);

      while(content.hasNextLine())
      {
         String s=content.nextLine();
         StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(s);
         buffer=buffer.reverse();
         String rs=buffer.toString();
         pwriter.println(rs);
      }
      content.close();    
      pwriter.close();
      System.out.println("File is copied successful!");
      }

      catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println("Something went wrong");
      }
   }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of a simple approach.

```
public class ReadFileReverse {

public int[] readByte(File _file) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream source = new FileInputStream(_file);
    int currentByte = source.available();
    int readCount = 0;

    int byteContainer[] = new int[currentByte];
    while(readCount < currentByte){
        byteContainer[readCount] = source.read();
        readCount++;
    }
    source.close();
    return byteContainer;
}

public void printReverse(int[] fileContent){
    for(int byt=fileContent.length -1; byt >= 0 ; byt--){
        System.out.print((char) fileContent[byt]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File fileToRead = new File("/README.txt");

    ReadFileReverse demo = new ReadFileReverse ();
    int[] readBytes = demo.readByte(fileToRead);

    demo.printReverse(readBytes);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we are reading a file in string variable, then making a String Builder object to perform reverse operation efficiently, then printing

```html
package com;

import java.io.FileReader;

public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  try {
   FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:\\newfile.txt");
   String str = "";
   int ch;
            //reading characters in to string variable
   while ((ch = fr.read()) != -1) {
    str += Character.toString((char) ch);
   }
   System.out.println("Original String : " + str);
            //converting string variable to String Builder object
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
            //reversing the string and printing
   System.out.println("Reverse order : " + sb.reverse());
   fr.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("error");
  }
 }
}
```

Output: [image]